# how to set the StatusBar font color of react-native in Android app?

Tags: react-native

in react native android app, I can use backgroundColor to set the `StatusBar` background color, but the font color is still white, I want to change to dark

Comment: My app is displaying black and I want it to be white. I wonder how it's choosing which color?

Answer (score 21):

If you want to change the text color to black you can use:

```
<StatusBar
 backgroundColor="#fff"
 barStyle="dark-content" // Here is where you change the font-color
/>
```

You can use **light-content** or **dark-content**.

Despite it's saying on the React Native page that only works on IOS, it actually works on Android as well.

*Tried on Android 6.0+ with RN 0.36.1*

Comment: Did not work on android react native 0.63

Answer (score 9):

use `style` to define the icon and text color and use `backgroundColor` to define the background.

```
<StatusBar style="light" backgroundColor="#000000" />
```

Comment: `barStyle="dark-content"` did not work on Android for me, `style="light"` did work. Note that one says "dark-content", the other one "light", while both of them turn text white.

Answer (score 0):

```
<StatusBar
 barStyle="dark-content"  <--- use this 
/>
```